# Compare a number in a switch statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, switch-statement

I need to compare an int in a switch statement, and I'm unsure of how I'm typing it wrong. Here's my code:

```
switch (y) {
    case int y isgreater(1, 411):
       // case code here...
```

To simplify what I want, in VB, the code would be:

```
Case >= 411:
  'Code here for case
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-based languages like Objective-C don't support that sort of syntax. Just use an `if` statement:

```
if (y >= 411) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In a `switch` statement, each `case` value must be a discrete constant.

```
switch (expression) {
    case 5:
        // stuff
        break;
    case 12:
        // stuff
        break:
    default:
        // stuff
        break;
}
```